# Different approaches to find the integral $\sin^6 x~dx$

Tags: integration

I noticed that using the integration reduction formula to reduce any nth term of sinx results in a different answer than reframing a power of sin^n x as (sin^2 x)^n/2.

The reduction formula:

```
 integral sin^n x dx = (-1/n)sin^(n-1)(x)*cos(x) + ((n-1)/n)*integral sin^(n-2)(x) dx
```

Using the reduction formula on integral sin^6(x) dx:

```
integral sin^6(x)dx = (-1/6)sin^5(x)cos(x) + [5/6] Integral sin^4(x) dx
integral sin^4(x)dx = (-1/4)sin^3(x)cos(x) + [3/4] Integral sin^2(x) dx
integral sin^2(x)dx = (-1/2)sin(x)cos(x) + [1/2] Integral sin^0(x) dx
```

Putting all that together gives:

```
integral sin^6(x) dx = (-1/6)sin^5(x)cos(x) + [5/6][(-1/4)sin^3(x)cos(x) + [3/4][(-1/2)sin(x)cos(x) + x/2]] + c
integral sin^6(x) dx = (-1/6)sin^5(x)cos(x) - [5/24]sin^3(x)cos(x) - [15/48]sin(x)cos(x) + 15/48 + c
```

However, integration by reframing sin^6 as (sin^2)^3 gives, what I'm assuming, the same answer but in a different form.

```
integral sin^6(x) dx = integral (sin^2(x))^3 dx 
= [(1-cos(2x)) / 2]^3
= [1/8] integral [1 - 3cos(2x) + 3cos^2(2x) + cos^3(2x)] dx

integral 1 dx = x
integral -3cos(2x) dx = [-3/2]sin(2x)
integral 3cos^2(2x) dx = integral [3/2][1+cos(4x)] dx 
    = [3/2]x + [3/8]sin(4x)
integral cos^3(2x) dx = integral cos^2(2x)*cos(2x) dx
    = integral (1-sin^2(2x))*cos(2x) dx, let u = sin(2x), du/(2cos(2x) = dx
    = integral [1/2] (1-u^2) dx
    = [1/2]u - [1/6]u^3 + c, substitute u = sin(2x)
    = [1/2]sin(2x) - [1/6]sin^3(2x) + c
```

Putting all that together gives:

```
[1/8][ x - [3/2]sin(2x) + [3/2]x + [3/8]sin(4x) + [1/2]sin(2x) - [1/6]sin^3(2x) ] + c
```

My question is (assuming I haven't made a mistake(lol)) can you convert one answer into the other?

Comment: You may compare with the [result from WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BPower%5Bsin+x%2C6%5D%2Cx%5D). But first please group like terms, like $x$ with $+[3/2]x$, $-[3/2]\sin(2x)$ with $+[1/2]\sin(2x)$, etc.

Comment: Thanks, any idea why the expanded trigonometric form has double the number of terms than my answer? I don't have pro so I can't see what their solution is.

Comment: My guess is that by different integration steps, they reached a form with higher odd powers of $\cos x$. Hopefully by $\cos^2 x = 1-\sin^2 x$, you might convert their result to yours in terms of $\sin^{k}(x)\cos(x)$.

Comment: @Moo nope. Havent had the time bwcause of school.